# How to send only one array value(without two value)?

Tags: reactjs

```
id: "a4a1e57b-f1c2-4a22-8b99-1ce2466719ba"
meetingDate: "2019-02-10T19:48:45"
members: [{memberId: "99489ea4-6d34-11e8-80cd-001dd8b71cd8", memberCode: "00-005424",…}]
0: {memberId: "99489ea4-6d34-11e8-80cd-001dd8b71cd8", memberCode: "00-005424",…}
   fullName: "Бағидолла Нұрсұлтан Маратұлы"// this 3 
   memberCode: "00-005424"
   memberId: "99489ea4-6d34-11e8-80cd-001dd8b71cd8"
```

I need to send only memberId value(in members array) with (,) in array how to do it? like

```
members [( 0: "99489ea4-6d34-11e8-80cd-001dd8b71cd8", 1: "99489ea4-6d34-11e8-80cd-001dd8b71cd8", 2: "99489ea4-6d34-11e8-80cd-001dd8b71cd8")]
```

Comment: Send where? It is completely unclear what are you asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var memberIds = members.map( m => m.memberId)
```

This will pick the member ids from your given data structure and store them in new array

Then you can mutate your original structure

```
{
  ... // other props
  members: memberIds
}
```

Since mutation is not recommended I will suggest to create a clone of original data and them mutate the clone